# SharePoint 2010: How do you reference the "Name" field when creating a lookup to a document library based on a document set?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm modifying the properties form of a SharePoint list that requires the user to select one or more items via a lookup to a document set. The document set library has a "Name" field which I cannot select as a field in my form's lookup properties.

The document set, of course, is a collection of documents grouped together with a common name, workflows, and metadata. The "name" I'm trying to display in my lookup list is set by the end user, but is inaccessible to me. Ideally, when someone is viewing an item in my SharePoint list (the one I'm trying to link from) and they see an associated document set item, they would be able to click on the name and it will take them to that element within the document set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using Name, try using Title.

Comment: Title, in this case, is not what the user wants to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got around this issue by creating a new workflow that fires any time a record is modified. This workflow sets a new text field to the value in the Name field. To apply this to existing records, I created a new checkbox field named "Fire Workflow", then went to the Datasheet view and checked that checkbox for all of the records. This forced the workflow to fire on each record and update the new text field.

Now I just reference this new text field for the lookup in my other library. All is good!